# Does a POD cache the files read in a container in POD's memory?

Tags: kubernetes

I am running an application in K8S POD.
Event though the applications memory usage is limited the PODs memory usage is growing till a certain limit and then remaining constant.

The application reads lot of input files are closes them.

Why us POD memory usage so high? Do PODs caches files inside POD memory, like OS.?
I am using Linux containers.

Comment: The container is not much more than your _process_. What kind of app is it? Is it Java?

Comment: Yes its java app.

Comment: the JVM eats memory for breakfast.... and keep it. Unless properly configured.

Comment: @Jonas agree !!

Comment: Actually its the Virtual Memory of the process which is too high and the used memory us less.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so because pods are ephemeral in nature. and as far as my point of view pod does not cause memory issue because of files. If it's java application then you have to limit the Heap usage by setting `JAVA_OPTS` as `env` and set the maximum memory limit in your deployment file. like this

```
env:
- name: JVM_OPTS
  value: "-Xms1048M -Xmx2048M"   # here xms value means starting memory for jvm and it can use upto 2048
```

Here is the very nice article https://banzaicloud.com/blog/java-resource-limits/

Comment: The java Process is not using much memory. Only the PODs memory is high.

Comment: Java process(Heap) causes to consume more memory for pod. We also had the same issue few months back so we fixed by doing it so

Answer (score 0):

> Even though the applications memory usage is limited

That is only the half of the story. In case of Java you need to consider JVM as well.

> the PODs memory usage is growing till a certain limit and then remaining constant.

There are limits for pods. You can get these limits with the help of `kubectl get pod <pod_name> -o yaml` (you are interested in the "requests" section).

> Why us POD memory usage so high?

You can check what *exactly* is going on with the help of `kubectl exec -it <pod_name> -- top -o RES -n1 | head` command. In this very example I'm sorting the output of `top` by the `RES` field. You can use any other fields ( for example `VIRT`, `SHR`, etc).

Here is the example from my machine:

```
$ kubectl get pod jenkins -o yaml | grep -A2 requests
      requests:
        cpu: 300m
        memory: 512Mi

$ kubectl top pod jenkins
NAME                           CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)   
jenkins                        3m           508Mi    

$ kubectl exec -it jenkins -- top -o RES -n1
...

PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                
  6 root      20   0 4478216 449952   8000 S   0.0  5.9  39:11.70 java
```

From the above output you can see that my jenkins pod has limit at 512Mi and consumes ~508Mi. You can get more insight on how exactly RAM is "wasted" by java app if you ran `pmap -x <pid>` , `ps -La -p <pid>` on pod.

It is worth checking `java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep Heap` and adjusting it with the Dashrath Mundkar's suggestion (if you would like to reduce the memory allocated by JVM inside your `pod`.

The following resources [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/180287/how-can-i-monitor-per-process-per-thread-memory-consumption-divided-into-heap), [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/892/is-there-a-way-to-see-details-of-all-the-threads-that-a-process-has-in-linux), [3](https://dzone.com/articles/how-much-memory-does-a-java-thread-take) might be useful here.